# Create a hierarchy from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a dictionary of lists:

```
a = {
        'a': [1, 2, 3],
        'b': [1, 2, 4],
        'c': [1, 2],
        'd': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'e': [3],
        'f': [3, 7],
        'g': [3, 3],
        'h': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        'i': [3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
    }
```

And I would like to create hierarchical structure from this dictionary which will group items in the similar manner (exact structure does not matter, as well as the relation between elements is preserved):

```
              /  \
             /    \
            e      c
           /\      /\
          f  g    a  b
             /\   |
            h  i  d
```

The hierarchy goes as follows: array `g` is a prefix of array `h` and `i` and therefore it is their ancestor. But `e` is a prefix of `g`, so it `e` is an ancestor of `g`.

**Here is my idea how to achieve this result.**

- Sort the dictionary based on the number of elements in the list, which I was able to achieve with `s = sorted(a.items(), key=lambda e: len(e[1]))`. This will give me the following structure:

.

```
('e', [3])
('c', [1, 2])
('g', [3, 3])
('f', [3, 7])
('a', [1, 2, 3])
('b', [1, 2, 4])
('d', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
('h', [3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

- Right now I can find first parents by iterating through elements and checking if an element is a prefix of other elements. Starting with the first one. `e` is a prefix of `g`, `f`, and `h`.  And `c` is a prefix of `a`, `b`, `d`. So these two elements are the parents.
- right now I understand that I have to use recursion to enter inside of each parent and to perform the same operation, but I was not able to come up with a right solution.

**So does anyone knows how to approach this problem**. Or am I over-complicating things and there is an easier way to achieve the solution.

P.S. this is not a homework assignment or interview question (also it might be). This is just my abstraction from a problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: I don't really see why you need recursion (thought I am sure it could be used somehow).  To do it in n^2, for each element, check all other elements to see if they are its child.  After that you should be done...

Comment: also you don't really need to check all other elements, just the ones after it in your sorted list (by length)

Comment: To me, it sounds like you are looking for a trie (aka prefix tree).[See trie on wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other people already give the methord, I just write some code here:

First sort:

```
t = sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

The build the structure

```
ret = {}

def build(ret, upv):
    if not t:
        return (None, None)
    k, v = t.pop(0)
    while k and v:
        if upv and v[:len(upv)] != upv:
            return (k, v)
        r = {}
        ret[k] = r
        k, v = build(r, v)
    return None, None

build(ret, None)
print ret
```

Comment: @SalvadorDali I tried on python 2.7.3, linux, it return {'c': {'a': {'d': {}}, 'b': {}}, 'e': {'g': {'i': {}, 'h': {}}, 'f': {}}}

Answer (score 0):

given an object that has a list of children, and an is_prefix function, and your sorted list of objects, I don't see why this wouldn't work

```
for indx, potential_prefix in enumerate(your_list):
    for potential_child in your_list[indx:]:
        if is_prefix(potential_prefix, potential_child):
            potential_prefix.add_child(potential_child)
            # and optionally
            potential_child.add_parent(potential_prefix)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about building the tree with a set of nested dictionaries, so that you'd access the `e` node by `tree[3]` and the `h` node by `tree[3][3][3][3][3]`:

```
from collections import nested

def nested():
    return defaultdict(nested)

def build_tree(data):
    tree = nested()
    for name, path in data.items():
        d = tree
        for p in path:
            d = d[p]
        d["value"] = name
    return tree
```

Example output:

```
>>> a = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [1, 2, 4],
    'c': [1, 2],
    'd': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'e': [3],
    'f': [3, 7],
    'g': [3, 3],
    'h': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'i': [3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
}

>>> import json # for pretty printing, note that in python the keys are ints, not str
>>> print(json.dumps(build_tree(a), indent=4))
{
    "1": {
        "2": {
            "3": {
                "4": {
                    "5": {
                        "value": "d"
                    }
                }, 
                "value": "a"
            }, 
            "4": {
                "value": "b"
            }, 
            "value": "c"
        }
    }, 
    "3": {
        "7": {
            "value": "f"
        }, 
        "3": {
            "3": {
                "3": {
                    "3": {
                        "value": "h"
                    }, 
                    "4": {
                        "value": "i"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            "value": "g"
        }, 
        "value": "e"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but it looks completely different from what I expect to get.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort arrays in lexicographical order:

```
(c,[1,2]),
(a,[1,2,3]),
(d,[1,2,3,4,5]),
(b,[1,2,4]),
(e,[3]),
(g,[3,3]),
(h,[3,3,3,3,3]),
(i,[3,3,3,3,4]),
(f,[3,7])
```

Then solution is pretty obvious.

```
root
Lc
|La
||Ld
|Lb
Le
 Lg
 |Lh
 |Li
 Lf
```

You need only track path form parent by prefix. From previous line. You will form somethink like stack. `root` has empty set so push it on stack. `c` has (empty) prefix as root so `root` is parent of `c`. Push `c` on stack. `a` has prefix which is `c` on top of stack so `c` is parent of `a`. push `a` on stack. `d` has prefix same as `a` on top of stack so `a` is parent of `d` and push on stack. `b` doesn't have prefix `d` on top of stack so pop. Same for `a` then pop. Now there is `c` which is prefix so `b` has parent `c`. Push `b` on stack.  And continue in same way.

In Erlang simply:

```
-module(tree_from_prefix).

-export([tree/1]).

is_prefix(_, []) -> true;
is_prefix([H|A], [H|B]) -> is_prefix(A, B);
is_prefix(_, _) -> false.

tree(L) ->
  tree(lists:keysort(2, L), [{root, []}]).

tree([], _) -> [];
tree([{X, L} = Record|T] = List, [{Parent, Prefix}|R] = Stack) ->
  case is_prefix(L, Prefix) of
    true -> [{Parent, X}|tree(T, [Record|Stack])];
    false -> tree(List, R)
  end.
```

And result

```
1> tree_from_prefix:tree([{e,[3]},{c,[1, 2]},{g,[3, 3]},{f,[3, 7]},{a,[1, 2, 3]},{b, [1, 2, 4]},{d,[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},{h,[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]},{i,[3, 3, 3, 3, 4]}]).
[{root,c},
 {c,a},
 {a,d},
 {c,b},
 {root,e},
 {e,g},
 {g,h},
 {g,i},
 {e,f}]
```

In python it will not be so elegant but same algorithm will work too.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to test it in Erlang first.